# Cursor spins on UI in a environment Linux and Real VNC

Tags: linux, vnc

An application is running in a Linux box. I use Real VNC Viewer to remote access the Linux box. When a dialog box pops up on the top of the application's main window, I move the cursor to the area between dialog and main window, the cursor starts to spin. If I move it back to dialog box, it becomes to a normal cursor. The spinning only occurs when I use Real VNC. If I use Nice DCV, there is no such issue. Is there any setting in Real VNC can change this behavior?

Comment: Cursor spinning should not be a problem.  Most likely just some setting they forgot to set -- is there a reason you want it changed?

Comment: @Alex Someone in my company filed a high priority defect for the spin. They thought initially its the UI's problem. I found it's specific to VNC. I hope there is a way to get rid of the spin.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  It's likely a bug with the VNC server itself -- have you tried installing a different version?  I am abroad right now, and away from my computer that has VNC servers installed, but I remember that the bugs in different versions would vary so much that I currently have 3 different versions installed, depending on what I wanted to do.  In other words, the newer version fixed one bug but introduced another one, so I had to pick which bug was more important to avoid, and that determined the version I used.

Comment: IT installed the new version of VNC. The spin is still there.